# OS X - Why is python not properly sourced in `which python`?... and is more broken in the system-level python?

Tags: osx, python, path, homebrew

TL;DR: Is this $PATH string backwards if I'm trying to source python 2.7 from the homebrew-installed version?

```
$ echo $PATH  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

---

I had used `brew install python` to put python 2.7.13 on El Capitan (OS X 10.11), and things were working fine for a while. Then I tried to deploy a venv, which went sideways, and I think my troubleshooting uncovered a deeper issue (or several). My goal is to have Python 2.7.x installed and functioning aside from OS X's python installation. I'm also aiming for `pip` and `venv`, in addition to some other imported modules to be installed with the brew-installed python 2.7 as well. (I understand messing with the system-original Python can cause deep, deep issues - so I'd like to leave it completely untouched.)

```
$ brew info python
python: stable 3.6.5 (bottled), devel 3.7.0b3, HEAD [pinned at 2.7.13]
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13 (6,337 files, 87.0MB) *
  Built from source on 2017-02-01 at 19:23:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
```

`brew info python` shows me that python 2.7.13 is installed and pinned. Great. However, if that's the case, why does `which python` point to the system-installed version?

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Checking $PATH, it looks like something went wrong there ...

```
$ echo $PATH  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

So my current $PATH is (`<cr>` after `:` for clarity):
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
- /usr/bin:
- /bin:
- /usr/sbin:
- /sbin:
- /usr/local/bin:
- /opt/X11/bin:
- /usr/local/git/bin

Should the proper $PATH order be
- /usr/local/bin:
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
- /usr/bin:
- /bin:
- /usr/sbin:
- /sbin:
- /opt/X11/bin:
- /usr/local/git/bin

According to [this page](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/), I need to add `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"` to my `.profile`, which gives me three questions:
1. Do I need to add `/usr/local/sbin` to my $PATH?
2. I thought my $PATH would persist through reboots - am I wrong?
3. If I need to add it to `~/.profile`, can I add it to `~/.bash_profile` instead?

---

Finally, here's one of the errors I'm seeing now:

```
$ vim peuler.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
ImportError: No module named time
An error occurred while importing powerline module.
This could be caused by invalid sys.path setting,
or by an incompatible Python version (powerline requires
Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later to work). Please consult
the troubleshooting section in the documentation for
possible solutions.
Unable to import powerline, is it installed?
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

To me, this indicates something went very wrong with the system-installed version of Python - is that the case? (No module named `time`? That can't be good..) Can I just rip out all of the homebrew-installed Python, ensure that the OS-installed version of Python is pure, and then re-install everything with homebrew?... or is the System-level Python totally jacked?

Comment: [Also posted here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15932/51)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know if my system-installed python is screwed up or not, but switching the PATH around solved the problem with the vim plugin.

The proper $PATH order be (again, `<cr>` added after `:` for clarity):
- /usr/local/bin:
- /usr/local/sbin:
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
- /usr/bin:
- /bin:
- /usr/sbin:
- /sbin:
- /opt/X11/bin:
- /usr/local/git/bin